# When did Dracula first say Blah Blah Blah?

Tags: history-of, dracula

In *Hotel Transylvania* Dracula is offended whenever anyone who is impersonating him says Blah Blah Blah.

In the Dracula mythos, when did Dracula first say Blah Blah Blah?

Comment: Was it in *Blacula*?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like [it's 1952 or 1953](https://maximumfun.org/news/history-and-origin-draculas-use-bizarre-expletive-bleh/), with Lugosi playing a parody of himself.

> Which leads to our second theory. Several listeners suggested that the phrase first appeared in a 1952 Bela Lugosi film called “My Son the Vampire”. Jamie McCormick wrote: “The earliest occurrence I can find of a Dracula character making the sound is from ‘My Son, The Vampire’, a 1953 musical satire starring Lugosi in essence mocking the franchise he himself created. Nosferatu, in company with the other early silent Dracula films, makes no reference to the sound, nor does Lugosi make the sound in his early and serious-minded Dracula films. Note especially the last line of the film’s title track – “He wants Bluuuuuuuuuuud!”

### My Son the Vampire

More pronounced in the 1964 Allan Sherman song:

### 1964 Allan Sherman - My Son, The Vampire

Comment: Okay, please don't make me wade through 80 minutes of Dracula meets the Three Stooges and Lost in Space to find a blah. I tried a few places where I saw Dracula show up, and the "old lady" is a great actor and all, but... Ha, the film breaks around 53 min in at a promising place. :sigh:

Comment: The timestamp for the second video is 0:32.